# Subdomains shows only php

Tags: php, apache, subdomain

I want to simple all subdomains from *.domain.com show content of domain.com with url of subdomain. But at now it's returning me php source instead of builded page. If using *.80 virtual host then all works, but subdomains show first site in www directory because both sites use same ip.

My file structure

```
www
 site1
 site2(which content i need to show with subdomains)
  content
  subdomain1
  subdomain2
  index.php
```

My virtualhost in apache2.conf code.

```
<VirtualHost IP:PORT>
    ServerName domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/path/data/www/domain.com
    ServerAlias *.domain.com
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.domain\.com$
    RewriteRule !^index\.php$ index.php [L]
</VirtualHost>
```

output

```
<?php require(dirname(__FILE__).'/config/config.inc.php'); 
Dispatcher::getInstance()->dispatch(); ?>
```